# How can I pass default checkbox inside multiple loop of id in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-redux, react-router

I'm working on react check box but I'm geting silly mistake of defaultCheckbox.

I'm calling an API to get the data and apply the map and passing a Input checkbox. So I'm getting multiple checkbox input.

I'm getting Error of check is not showing on multiple inputs when I'm editing it. Please anyone can help and suggest to me how can I solve this issue of checkbox?

this is image here is showing only one checkbox, but im pasing this id for all product by props
[image]

I'm using this code. I'm guessing that I need to apply any loop for check each product id.

```js
<div key={"row-expanded-" + item.id}>
  {item.SubCategories.map((subval, i) => (
    <div key={subval.id} className="form-check mx-2">
      <p
        style={{
          fontWeight: "bold",
          color: "black",
          textDecoration: "none",
        }}
      >
        - {subval.sub_name}
      </p>
      {subval.products.map((p, index) => (
        <div key={p.id} className="form-check mx-2">
          <div class="form-check row">
            <input
              className="form-check-input mt-1"
              key={i}
              type="checkbox"
              value={p.id}
              defaultChecked={
                p.id == this.props.rowRcData[index] ? true : null
              }
              onChange={event => this.handleChangesub(event, i, p)}
            />
            <label className="label-brand mx-4 ml-4">{p.name}</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  ))}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DataTable of React and can easily make anythings using this format. Use My Code-

const columns = [
{
id: 1,
name: "S.no",
selector: (row) => row.id,
sortable: true,
reorder: true,
},
{
id: 2,
name: "Email / Phone",
selector: (row) => row.email,
sortable: true,
reorder: true,
},
{
id: 3,
name: "Username",
selector: (row) => row.username,
sortable: true,
reorder: true,
},

```
{
  id: 4,
  name: "User Type",
  selector: (row) => (row.role == 1 ? "Admin" : "User"),
  sortable: true,
  right: true,
  reorder: true,
},
{
  id: 5,
  name: "",
  // selector: (row) => row.role,
  sortable: true,
  right: true,
  reorder: true,
},
{
  id: 6,
  name: "Action",
  button: true,
  cell: (row) => (
    <React.Fragment>
      <button
        className="btn btn-sm btn-light"
        onClick={() => onDelete(row._id)}
      >
        <i className="bx bx-trash me-0"></i>
      </button>
      &nbsp;
      <input type="checkbox"/>
      
    </React.Fragment>
  ),
},
```

];

```
<DataTable
        style={{ background: "transparent" }}
        title="User"
        columns={columns}
        defaultSortFieldId={1}
        sortIcon={<ArrowUpwardIcon />}
        pagination
      />
```

[image: Table Looks Like this use css for checkbox]